# Internet Explorer hiding iframe when its supposed to show on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, youtube

I created a simple mouse over that shows a youtube video using iframe embed.

The mouse over is: Hover A to show B and if you hover over B, B stays shown until you hover over something else that is not A or B.

If you notice, if I hover over the white space of the green box, which is B, it stays on, but as soon as I move mouse over the iframe/youtube video it disappears.

HTML

```
<div class="a">cool</div>
<div class="b"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xrMOBKHqqc8?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

CSS

```
.a { border: solid blue; height: 20px; }
.b {display: none; border: solid green; }
.a:hover + .b { display: block; }
.b:hover { display: block; }
```

**[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/X5br3/18/)**

BTW I am using IE 11. Firefox and Chrome do not have this problem.

Any possible solutions/suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have `IE11` at the moment. However, I tried your demo link on `IE10` and it worked just fine.

Comment: I can see the issue on IE11. Not quite sure what exactly is causing the issue. In any case, how about using a wrapper div around both elements? And then something like `.wrapper:hover .b { display:block; }` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
iframe { position: relative; z-index:-1; }
```

Can be `.b iframe {` also.

Comment: this works on the JS fiddle, but for some reason it's not working on my site ugh... I'll investigate more when I wakeup tomorrow.

Comment: What is this dark sorcery?! :D

Answer (score 1):

How about using this code? 
http://jsfiddle.net/X5br3/37/

IE11 tested

```
.a { border: solid blue; height: 20px; }

.b {display: none; border: solid green; }

.a:hover + .b { display: block; }

.b:hover { display: block; }

/* added */
.b iframe {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```